# SwiftIUI - TabView not sticking to bottom of view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a custom tabview:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomTabBar: View {
var animation: Namespace.ID
@Binding var currentTab: Tab
var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(Tab.allCases, id: \.rawValue) {tab in
            TabButton(tab: tab, animation: animation, currentTab: $currentTab) { pressedTab in
                withAnimation(.spring()) {
                    currentTab = pressedTab
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

struct TabButton: View {
var tab: Tab
var animation: Namespace.ID
@Binding var currentTab: Tab
var onTap: (Tab)->()

var body: some View {
    Image(tab.rawValue)
        .renderingMode(.original)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 27, height: 27)
        .foregroundColor(currentTab == tab ? .white : .gray)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50 )
        .background(
            ZStack {
                if currentTab == tab {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color("startColor"))
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "TAB", in: animation)
                }
            }
        )
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .onTapGesture {
            onTap(tab)
        }
}
}
```

My Main View where I use the customTabBar:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

@State var currentTab : Tab = .Home
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
}
@Namespace var animation

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
            HomeView()
                .tag(Tab.Home)
            
            SearchView()
                .tag(Tab.Search)
            
            MessagesView()
                .tag(Tab.Messages)
            
            SettingsView()
                .tag(Tab.Settings)
        }
        CustomTabBar(animation: animation, currentTab: $currentTab)
    }
}
}

enum Tab: String, CaseIterable {
case Home = "Home"
case Search = "Search"
case Messages = "Messages"
case Settings = "Settings"
}


struct MainView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    MainView()
}
}
```

When I click to get the keyboard to show up and the keyboard appears, the view gets pushed up which is ok, but the TabView is also getting brought up to the top, this should stay at the bottom.

How can I make the TabView stick to the bottom and not come up when the keyboard comes up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way do achieve this could be to use the `.position` modifier, but it requires knowing the height of the tab view upfront (which is fixed in your case, so it should work).

```
struct MainView: View {
    
    @State var currentTab : Tab = .Home
    @State var screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    @State var safeSize: EdgeInsets = EdgeInsets()
    
    init() {
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true
    }
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                    HomeView()
                        .tag(Tab.Home)
                    
                    SearchView()
                        .tag(Tab.Search)
                    
                    MessagesView()
                        .tag(Tab.Messages)
                    
                    SettingsView()
                        .tag(Tab.Settings)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    // Get the safe area on the first draw (only),
                    // this should get the max safe area
                    self.safeSize = geometry.safeAreaInsets
                }
                
                CustomTabBar(animation: animation, currentTab: $currentTab)
                    // stick it to the bottom of the original safe area
                    .position(x: screenSize.width / 2, y: screenSize.height - safeSize.bottom - safeSize.top - 25 /* half of the tab frame height */)
            }
        }
    }
}
```